# How to work with a multiprocessing.Manager() Array in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm launching a worker process using Python's multiprocessing. I need to be able to update an array in the subprocess that can be seen in the parent process. I use `multiprocessing.Manager()` to accomplish that.

```
a = multiprocessing.Manager().Array('f', [0,0])
a
<ArrayProxy object, typeid 'Array' at 0x7f4e2b4eeda0>

a.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ArrayProxy' object has no attribute 'value'
```

When I create a `Value('f', 0.0)` I can operate on it this way. When I look at `dir(a)` I don't see any obvious functions or attributes to call, and the documentation in python is really fuzzy about this point.

Comment: A normal `array.array` object doesn't have a `.value` attribute, either. What do you expect that to contain?

Comment: Have you ***actually tried updating*** the `ArrayProxy` object? It doesn't seem like that's what you're doing here.

Comment: I have sent it across to the other process. I can print it and see the values, and just realized I can access each of the values with a[i]. So I'm guessing that's the only way to actually update the values of the array in the subprocess. I was expecting to be able to set the entire array in one step rather than iterating over each element and updating it (which won't be an atomic operation either). My goal is simply to update the value of the array in the subprocess in an atomic way that is then visible to the parent process. A reasonable expectation seems to be `a.set_value([1.0,2.0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is a [proxy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects) object

```
<ArrayProxy object, typeid 'Array' at 0x7f4e2b4eeda0>
```

> A proxy is an object which refers to a shared object which lives (presumably) in a different process. The shared object is said to be the referent of the proxy.

The relationship between *proxy object* and the *real object* as following shown, in **multiprocessing/managers.py**

```
SyncManager.register('Value', Value, ValueProxy)
SyncManager.register('Array', Array, ArrayProxy)
```

And we see the supported operators of **ArrayProxy**

```
ArrayProxy = MakeProxyType('ArrayProxy', (
    '__len__', '__getitem__', '__setitem__', '__getslice__', '__setslice__'
    ))                  # XXX __getslice__ and __setslice__ unneeded in Py3.0
```

The **Array** is actually `array.array(...)`

[Value(typecode, value)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Value) is different from **Array**

> Create an object with a writable `value` attribute and return a proxy for it.

```
class ValueProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('get', 'set')
    def get(self):
        return self._callmethod('get')
    def set(self, value):
        return self._callmethod('set', (value,))
    value = property(get, set)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to update multiple values inside a `Array` atomically.

In this case, I suggest you:

```
a.acquire()  # Using its internal lock object
a[0] = ...   # Do what ever you want
a[1] = ...
a.release()
```

Comment: Or you can do something like `a[:] = [1, 2,3]`.